# XMPPFramework Swift delegate functions not being called

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

I've modified [this](https://github.com/inaka/ios-xmpp-sample)! simple XMPP example from Erlang by adding the delegate function (next to the other three functions in the delegate extension):

```
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive iq: XMPPIQ) -> Bool {
    print("Did receive IQ")
    return false
}
```

So, I can see the IQ messages in the log stream, but it doesn't print "Did receive IQ".  The same thing happens with didReceiveMessage.

Comment: can you post the stream log?

Comment: The log like is below.  Overall, I'm now more concerned about the lack of use of Swift and XMPP.  I would suggest that companies like Process 1 and Erland invest more in the XMPPFramework for IOS.  I don't want to use firebase, but that solution is looking much more attractive now.  Log: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WMhPMEhXNpqGSt3WCdof8rcp1yvrOGPVRnDodNUkCyU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, and this is how far I got - I ended up backtracking the "message" element to this point:

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Core/XMPPStream.m#L3158

From there, the multicastDelegate doesn't send it out.

Comment: Last comment - for anyone who is interested in adding messaging to their app - use Firebase.  I'm biased to open frameworks, but forget it.  Just use Firebase. Their Firestore DB blows everything out of the water.  Google has won.  You can build a chat system in a day.  I don't know if XMPP has any relevant advantages, but I know about the many disadvantages.

Comment: Very last comment - I switched to RabbitMQ (with the apps using MQTT protocol) and Socket.IO.  The apps have SQLite databases that store the messages once received.  I added end-to-end encryption.  Since there is proper server redundancy I don't even store the messages in the DB.  Firebase is relegated to only storing user images and videos (Cloud Storage Service).